# GetServerSideProps Query URL parameters

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to query the parameter in the url inside getServerSideProps. However, I get the error below and ID is undefined in the DetailThemepage function. I use Next.js V.13. Directory structure: app/detail/[id]/page.tsx

> http://localhost:3000/detail/xyz

```
export default async function DetailThemepage({ id }: { id: string }) {
//ID IS UNDEFINED
console.log("ID OF THE PAGE:" + id);

...

}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
const { id } = context.query;

return {
 props: {
  id,
  },
 };
};
```

> "getServerSideProps" is not a valid Next.js entry export value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Next.js 13, getServerSideProps is not supported in the app directory

https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fundamentals

Instead the DetailThemepage function can take a params argument and can be written as below

```
export default async function DetailThemepage({ params, searchParams }: { params: { id: string }; searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined } }) {
    console.log("ID OF THE PAGE:" + params.id);
}
```

https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/page

Answer (score 0):

`getServerSideProps` is not a valid method for querying the url-params in a server component anymore. Try deleting the whole `getServerSideProps` part and see if it works.

"*All components inside the app directory are React Server Components (RSC) by default*" - [new next docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#sharing-data-between-server-components)